# How to increment +1 in .times iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  <% @challenge.days_challenged.times do %>
    <div class="text-background">
      Day <%= + 1 %>
       <%= render "notes/notes" %>
       <%= render "notes/form" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Every note has "Day 1" at the top instead of "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", etc depending on how many `@challenge.days_challenged`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use counter like so:

```
<% @challenge.days_challenged.times do |counter| %>
  <div class="text-background">
    Day <%= counter + 1 %>
    <%= render "notes/notes" %>
    <%= render "notes/form" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here, `.times` would pass the current *step* of the iteration starting from 0 to your block.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `days_challenged#times` is an array of the days...

```
  days_challenged.times.each do |day|
    puts "Day #{day}"
  end
```

outputs each day

Comment: Thanks for your help! Maybe someday I'll switch it over, but for now it's a fixnum

Comment: You inspired me to solve a new problem :] I'm trying to use `days_challenged` to now make an array of dates `dates_challenged` if you can offer anymore insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755716/how-to-make-integer-into-array-of-dates